# PHP MySQL - DESC LIMIT disables ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am kinda new to MySQL and I am trying to order messages by date. And I also want to show no more than 10 messages. My query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `id`, `Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM vraagstellen ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
```

The order by gets disabled. Anyone who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, it is loading, but the ORDER BY is not working anymore. If I delete "DESC LIMIT 10" the order by is correct.

Comment: Maybe you will order "ASC" not "DESC"?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted! Sorry I am kinda newby in this haha

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `id`, `Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as date_formatted FROM vraagstellen ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Your code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `id`, `Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM vraagstellen ORDER BY date DISC LIMIT 10";
```

- DISC -> DESC
- added `as date_formatted`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ORDER BY date DISC
```

to

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Tried it, it is loading, but the ORDER BY is not working anymore. If I delete "DESC LIMIT 10" the order by is correct.

Answer (score 0):

change DISC to DESC

try using: `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10`

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id, Afbeelding, Vraag, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as newdate FROM vraagstellen ORDER BY newdate DESC LIMIT 10";
```

now access `date` field using `newdate`